# vue dosent' show data when loaded from firestore

Tags: javascript, vue.js, google-cloud-firestore

I have build a hierarchy in firestore with a country having a subcollection of a lower collection of documents, with a name defined when data is stored, so it will have to be rendered manually.

This works fine in the following code (not an expert js/vue developer so please bear over with me). Below is run at mounted

```
async getGeoHierarchy(vPath,vStep,vCounter,vGeographies){
            console.log(vPath)
            const vTempGeo = [];
            await db.collection(vPath)
                .get()
                .then(function(querySnapshot) {
                    querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        // doc.data() is never undefined for query doc snapshots
                        const vCollections = doc.data().collections;
                        vTempGeo.push({
                            name: doc.data().name,
                            id: doc.id,
                            collection: vCollections,
                            path: vPath + "/" + doc.id,
                            level: vStep,
    
                        })
                    });
                });
            //debugger;
            console.table(vGeographies);
            for(let i=0; i<vTempGeo.length;i++){
                vGeographies.splice(vCounter+i,0,vTempGeo[i]);
            }
            const lGeographies = vGeographies.length;
            for (let i=vStep; i<lGeographies;i++){
                const vCurrent = vGeographies[i];
                //debugger
                if(Array.isArray(vCurrent.collection)){
                    
                    for(let j=0; j < vCurrent.collection.length; j++){
                        await this.getGeoHierarchy(vCurrent.path+"/"+vCurrent.collection[j],vStep+i+j+1,vCounter+1,vGeographies);
                    }
                }
            }
            console.table(vGeographies);
            this.Geographies = vGeographies;
            console.table(this.Geographies);
            await this.populateGeoData(0);

            return vPath
        }
```

The toplevel i.e. "Country" must generate a new v-card, so I'll have to change the data into a different structure:

```
async populateGeoData(vTopLevel) {
            let vTempArr = [];
            let vTopLevelData = [];
            let vTempGeo = [];
            
            let vFirst = true;
            let vTopLevelCounter = 0;
            
            // debugger
            for(let i =0; i < this.Geographies.length; i++){
                if(this.Geographies[i].level==vTopLevel){
                    if(!vFirst || i==this.Geographies.length-1) {
                        vTempGeo[0] = vTopLevelData;
                        vTempGeo[1] = vTempArr;
                        this.vGeoData[vTopLevelCounter] = vTempGeo;
                        vTempGeo = []
                        if(i==this.Geographies.length-1){
                            vTempGeo[0] = this.Geographies[i];
                            vTempGeo[1] = [];
                            vTopLevelCounter++;
                            this.vGeoData[vTopLevelCounter] = vTempGeo;
                        }
                        vTempGeo = [];
                        vTopLevelCounter++;
                    }
                    vTopLevelData = this.Geographies[i];
                    vTempArr = [];
                    vFirst = false;
                }
                else {
                    vTempArr.push(this.Geographies[i])
                }
            }
        console.table(this.vGeoData)
        return this.vGeoData;
        }
```

This works fine the first time I save the code in the template, but when I refresh it's like vue does not show the data. According to vue-devtools, the data has loaded fine.

This is the template:

```
<template>
  <div class="pt-3">
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center">
      <v-col cols=4>
        <v-text-field
          label="Nyt land"
          outlined v-model="newItem"
          @keyup.enter="addItem"/>
      </v-col>
      <v-col cols=4>
        <v-text-field
          label="Region"
          outlined v-model="newRegion"
          @keyup.enter="addItem"/>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row class="d-flex justify-center">
        <v-col cols=1>
          <v-btn color="primary" @click="addItem">Tilføj land</v-btn>
      </v-col>
    </v-row>
    <v-row >
        <v-col>
            <v-card v-for="(geography,id) in vGeoData" :key="id">
                <v-card-title>{{geography[0].name | capitalize }} </v-card-title>
                <v-card-text>  tests</v-card-text>
            </v-card>
        </v-col>
    </v-row>
  </div>
</template>
```

And this is the data section of the :

```
data() {
        return {
            Geographies:[],
            newItem: "",
            newRegion:"",
            vFirst:true,
            vTopLevel:0,
            vGeoData: [],
            vToplevelData: [],


        }
    }
```

Any pointers will be highly appreciated

BR
Rune.

Comment: I don't think I would be able to help unless you provide me with a full reproducible code. Github link might be useful. can you elaborate on `I have build a hierarchy in firestore with a country having a subcollection of a lower collection of documents, with a name defined when data is stored` and `This works fine the first time I save the code in the template, but when I refresh it's like vue does not show the data.` ? also read more here on [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: Thanks, Methkal. I don’t know if I can build a reproducible example, as it connects to firestore and I don’t want to disclose username//password. I don’t think firebase is the issue as data are returned fine. It most be in the way I invoke vue. It is as it doesn’t recognize that the data is updated async.